Tailwind custom colors along with default colors
In my tailwind config, i would like to be able to add some custom colors BUT also use all of tailwinds as well, e.g. i add a green but then can also use green-500.
Here is my config:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  variants: {
    extend: {
      display: ['group-hover'],
    },
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        pulse: 'pulse 2s infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        pulse: {
          '0%, 100%': { opacity: 1 },
          '50%': { opacity: 0.5 },
        },
      },
      borderWidth: {
        1: '1px',
      },
      spacing: {
        18: '4.5rem',
      },
      colors: {
        dark: '#242424',
        paperdark: '#343434',
        bright: '#f1f0eb',
        cyan: '#5ccabe',
        green: '#71b468',
        red: '#ee6022',
        white: '#ffffff',
      },
    },
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
  plugins: [require('tailwind-scrollbar')({ nocompatible: true })],
};

But whenever I try to use like text-blue-500 or bg-blue-500 i dont see the color.

You could as replace as add your custom naming
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
  prefix: '',
  theme: {
      extend: {
        colors: {
          green: {
            DEFAULT: '#555652' //to change the default value for green
            10: "#111111" // to add custom name as part of whole greens
          }
        },
      },
    },
};


You could try adding the color to green-* instead of replacing the original green property.
When extending colors in extend, the original colors will be inherited directly. You only need to add your colors to the corresponding color property object:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        green: {
          custom: '#71b468', // <-- Add your custom green colors in this object.
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Usage:
<div class="bg-green-custom h-32"></div>
<div class="bg-green-500 h-32"></div>


Demo on Tailwind Play.

I added blue: {
...colors.blue,
} but i still see no color when I use it. e.g. text-blue-500

make sure you'e not using the old built assets!

@strangeQuirks Could you update the question description with this specific situation? What does your configuration file look like now?
I just tried it, and you don't even need to include the previous colors in extend. You just need to make sure you're providing an object (like green: { custom: '#71b468' }).
